# How to trigger a javascript function on appearence of an element

Tags: javascript, triggers

Hi,

I need to execute a javascript function once as soon as an element with a given class appears on the code (the element will be generated by another script).

This is my function:

```
play(sound);
```

the element would appear inside this:

```
<div id="canvas">
```

The element would look like this:

```
<span class="sound">sound name</span>
```

where "sound name" will determine the argument for play();

how can this be done with javascript?

Thank you.

Comment: `(the element will be generated by another script)` - have that other script run `play(sound)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a You could use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) as shown below.

The second argument to `.observe()`, `MutationObserverInit`, is important:

In the options, use `childList: true` if the `span` will only be added as a direct child. `subTree: true` if it can be at any level down below `#canvas`.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

- `childList`: Set to `true` if additions and removals of the target node's child elements (including text nodes) are to be observed.
- `subtree`: Set to `true` if mutations to target and target's descendants are to be observed.

```js
$("#go").click(function () {
    $("#canvas").append($('<span class="sound">sound name</span>'));
});

function play(n) { alert('playing '+ n); }

var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
  $.each(mutations, function (i, mutation) {
    var addedNodes = $(mutation.addedNodes);
    var selector = "span.sound"
    var spanSounds = addedNodes.find(selector).addBack(selector); // finds either added alone or as tree
    spanSounds.each(function () { // handles any number of added spans
      play($(this).text());
    });
  });
});

obs.observe($("#canvas")[0], {childList: true, subtree: true});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="canvas"></div>

<button id="go">Add span to canvas</button>
```

## Using plain JavaScript

The code is a little less compact, but it is definitely doable:

```js
document.getElementById("go").addEventListener('click', function () {
  var s = document.createElement('span');
  s.innerText = 'sound name';
  s.classList.add('sound')
  document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(s);
});

function play(n) { alert('playing '+ n); }

var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
  for(var i=0; i<mutations.length; ++i) {
    for(var j=0; j<mutations[i].addedNodes.length; ++j) {
      var addedNode = mutations[i].addedNodes[j];
      //NOTE: if the element was added as child of another element, you would have to traverse
      // the addedNode to find it. I recommend the jQuery solution above if that's the case
      if(addedNode.tagName == "SPAN" && addedNode.classList.contains("sound")) {
        play(addedNode.innerText);
      }
    }
  }
});

obs.observe(document.getElementById('canvas'), {childList: true, subtree: true});
```

```html
<div id="canvas"></div>

<button id="go">Add span to canvas</button>
```

Comment: it works great here on the snippet but for some reason I cant get it to work on my actual code and I dont get any error on the console so I cant debug it. How can I know whats going wrong?

Comment: Are you using `[0]` when passing the argument to the `obs.observe()`?

Comment: Hum.. have you tried adding some `console.log()`s around? If you want, you can paste the important parts in a JSFiddle and paste the link here so I can take a look.

Comment: The code is quite complex to post it all here. It would be easier to see the actual site. Should I include console.log() within your code so I can see whats wrong?

Comment: I dont get it. I even placed the code in an external file and I am loading it from there but no result. I dont get any errors either so I dont know how to address the problem.

Comment: What code?  Can you paste it here : http://jsfiddle.net (hit save above) and paste the link here?

Comment: The code you posted. It works fine here but not on my actual site and since I dont get any errors on the console I dont know whats wrong.

Comment: Yeah, but if you don't show me anything, I won't be able to help you.. Can't you give me any more details?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167965/discussion-between-cain-nuke-and-acdcjunior).

Comment: I wanted to thank you again for your kind help and also apologize about the chrome thing. Actually the "ahhhhhh" sound was coming out of firefox because I had the window open which confused me. Sorry, I guess I was already too tired and didnt see that but the code works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, I just came across a little problem. Remember the part that triggers the sound? playSound('gasp'); I temporarily set it like this for testing purposes but its supposed to have a variable the same way you posted it first playSound($(this).text()) but its not working and I am not getting any error on the console that allows me to find out whats wrong.

Comment: Do `console.log('text: ', $(this).text());`.  What does it output?

Comment: The log shows the text just fine but its not working. In fact, I can only see the log like this playSound('gasp');
      console.log('text: ', $(this).text()); because if I do like this playSound($(this).text());
      console.log('text: ', $(this).text());  then the log isnot shown.

Comment: How about: `var txt = $(this).text();
playSound(txt);
console.log('text: ', txt);`?

Comment: I tried but it wont work either. With playSound it wont work at all and with console.log only works if I dont use the variable with playSound as well. Its really weird!

Comment: And this: `var txt = $(this).text(); console.log('text1: ', txt); playSound(txt);  console.log('text2: ', txt);`?

Comment: now text1 shows on the log but playSound wont work and text2 doesnt show

Comment: Maybe it is throwing an exception: `var txt = $(this).text(); console.log('text1: ', txt); try{ playSound(txt); }catch(e){console.log('Error!', e);} console.log('text2: ', txt);`

Comment: it says this text1:   Snoring
sounds.js:83:7
Error! 
TypeError: sounds[name] is undefined
Stack trace:
playSound@js/sounds.js:44:7
addPlayObserver/obs</</<@js/sounds.js:84:12
each@js/jquery.min.2.1.1.js:2:2878
each@js/jquery.min.2.1.1.js:2:845
addPlayObserver/obs</<@js/sounds.js:81:21
each@js/jquery.min.2.1.1.js:2:2878
addPlayObserver/obs<@js/sounds.js:79:17
sounds.js:85:16
text2:   Snoring

Comment: I took a look at it. You have a whitespace char before the name. Trim it: `playSound($(this).text().trim());`

Comment: Great, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49678867/how-can-i-load-data-in-a-file-on-the-server-side-from-a-client-side-file I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try [onload event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You need a listener to detect the DOM change, [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
var targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        }
        else if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: interesting, is this code placed at the end of the file or after the div?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly your question. It is js code, generally placed in an external file at the end of HTML before </body>, like so:
        <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
    </body>

Comment: Okay, its just that most of the times its inside <head>